# How to return a string based on correspondent values summed from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

As the topic states what is the best way to make it so that when you pass an array of emotions/values, to show the closest value based on a numeric mapping in javascript?.

Assume that 'Glad' is the same thing as 'Happy', and 'Down' is the same thing as 'Sad'. Ithe code I've tried seems incredibly lengthy and gets bloated if I add more emotions/states (i.e. Angry). Aside from the emotions array, any new functions and data structures and variables can be changed/introduced.

for example, I can get a list of emotions:

```
let emotions = ['Happy','Happy','Sad','Glad','Angry'];
```

Now I want to return a string that reflects what the 'closest' emotion based on these 5 emotions.

For a better example, let's assume the values correspondent to each emotion is:

> Angry = 1, Happy = 2, Sad = 3

I was trying something like:

```js
var numb = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < emotions.length; i++) {
  if (numb == 'Angry')
    numb += 1;
  if (numb == 'Happy' || numb == 'Glad')
    numb += 2;
  if (numb == 'Sad' || numb == 'Down')
    numb += 3;
}
var average = numb / emotions.length;

// check which number is closer to
if (average < 1.5)
  return 'Angry';
if (average >= 1.5 && < 2.5)
  return 'Happy';
if (average > 2.5)
  return 'Sad';
if (average == 1.5)
  return 'Angry or Happy';
if (average == 2.5)
  return 'Happy or Sad';
```

My **expected result** based on this list of emotions is:
`2(*Happy*) + 2(*Happy*) + 3(*Sad*) + 2(*Happy|Glad*) + 1(*Angry*) = 10`
Then divide by 5 (the emotions array length), resulting in 2.
So the result that should be returned, as string, is **`"Happy"`**.

Let's say I added a fourth type of emotion/feeling... I would be adding more and more of these conditions, and it gets more complicated in the logic checking for the ranges of the numbers.

I am looking at the list of emotions as a whole, and trying to come up with an overall emotion that represents the whole list.

What is the best way to do this so that the code looks clean and I can support more states without having the lines of code become too long?

Comment: `Math.round()?`

Comment: @CalvinNunes That could be a part of it, but in my case I want it so that 1.5 would mean 'Happy or Sad' (the middle ground) and not just default to rounding up.

Comment: I kinda think this question might have a better home on https://codereview.stackexchange.com - you could check out their topic rules

Comment: Are you wanting to use the array index to get the string? You could strip the decimal (if not a whole number), then get `emotions[x] + ' or ' + emotions[x + 1]`

Comment: You could also directly assign ranges to each emotion, like between 1 and 10, between 10 and 20 etc. That way it also becomes easy to make certain results more common than others, by giving them a bigger range. Having 5 be `Happy or Sad` is then just something like: `[{ emo: 'happy', min: 0, max: 5 },{ emo: 'happy or sad', min: 5, max: 6 },{ emo: 'sad', min: 6, max: 11 }]` and then `.find( item => val >= item.min && val < item.max )`.

Comment: @TimLewis my ultimate result is to get to the string.

Comment: I think there's some confusion here. Is the user passing an array of emotions (strings) or an array of float values?

Comment: @TimLewis User is passing an array of emotions. Updated original post for increased clarity.

Comment: Expected result is the emotion that it is closest to, so 2(Happy) + 2(Happy) + 3(Sad) + 2(Happy) + 1(Angry) = 10, then divide by 5 (Total Number of Items in Emotions Array) is equal to 2. So the result is 'Happy'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this:

Having two object constants: 
`emotionsValues`: Here you assing a value to each emotion you want, like a score to each.

`emotionsRank`: Here is the final result of each value, based on average you'll get the result from here.

Now:

1. Receive the emotions array by parameter.
2. `reduce` it based on the value of each mapped emotion (using `emotionsValues`).
3. Get the average
4. See if the floor value + ceil value divided by 2 is equal to the number itself (it means its exactly the half), so use the "emotion or emotion".
5. OR, if not the half, then round to the nearest and get the correct emotion. Don't forget to check if average is below 1 or bigger the the last rank (3 in this case)

```js
const emotionsValues = {
  "Angry": 1,
  "Happy": 2,
  "Glad": 2,
  "Sad": 3,
  "Down": 3,
}

const emotionsRank = {
  1: "Angry",
  2: "Happy",
  3: "Sad",
}

function getEmotion(arrayEmot) {
  let numb = arrayEmot.reduce((acc, v) => Number(emotionsValues[v]) + acc, 0);

  let avg = numb / arrayEmot.length;
  let min = Math.floor(avg)
  let max = Math.ceil(avg)

  if ((min + max) / 2 == avg && min != max) {
    return emotionsRank[min] + " or " + emotionsRank[max]
  } else {
    let rounded = avg < 1 ? 1 : avg > 3 ? 3 : Math.round(avg);    
    return emotionsRank[rounded];
  }
}

let emotionsTest = ['Happy', 'Happy', 'Sad', 'Glad', 'Angry'];
console.log(getEmotion(emotionsTest))

let emotionsTest2 = ['Happy', 'Happy', 'Sad', 'Sad'];
console.log(getEmotion(emotionsTest2))
```

Comment: Is this accounting for the average of all emotions though? Like if there was overwhelming number of Angry's there... would this account for that? Looking at this, it seems like it just accounts for the min/max, but not the amount/number of each emotion. I am looking at the list of emotions as a whole, and trying to come up with an overall emotion that represents the whole list.

Comment: I think it is a little confusion to understand your goal and from where does the array of emotios come from... but no, it's only based on an average number, not based on array, now that you said, I finally understood your goal... I have little time now, but if I can, I would edit and try to answer what you really need

Comment: Can you post on your question, the values for all emotions, (1=happy, 2=sad,...)? And also, does `emotions` array be received by parameter? Can't you use the first part of your code, that checks the `numb` and `average`, then get this average and pass to my function of `getEmotion`, wont it result in your desired goal?

Comment: 1-Angry, 2-Happy, 3-Sad. It can be received by parameter. Yes, you can do that.

Comment: @Rolando I think that my edit do what you need, please review it

Answer (score 1):

- You may create the function emo to value and its reciprocal one: value to emotionS:
- Then you map every emotions found in array to its value
- do your standard mathematical stuff
- and get back to emotions via the reciprocal function

```js
const emoToValue = {
  Glad: 1,
  Happy: 1,
  Sad: 2
}

const valueToEmos = Object.entries(emoToValue).reduce((acc, [emo, val]) => {
  acc[val] = acc[val] || []
  acc[val].push(emo)
  return acc
}, {})

//compute the average:
function avgEmotion (emotions) {
  if (emotions.length == 0) return ''
  const avg = emotions.reduce((s, em) => s + emoToValue[em], 0) / emotions.length
  return valueToEmos[Math.round(avg)].join(' or ')
}

console.log('str', avgEmotion(['Happy', 'Happy', 'Sad', 'Happy'])) //Glad or Happy
console.log('str', avgEmotion(['Happy', 'Happy', 'Sad', 'Sad'])) //Sad
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a set of indices and get the values by filtering with the index.

```js
function getEmotion(emotions, value) {
    var values = new Set([value + 0.5, value - 0.5, Math.round(value)]);
    return emotions.filter((e, i) => values.has(i + 1)).join(' and ');
}

console.log(getEmotion(['Happy', 'Sad', 'Glad', "Angry"], 1));
console.log(getEmotion(['Happy', 'Sad', 'Glad', "Angry"], 1.5));
console.log(getEmotion(['Happy', 'Sad', 'Glad', "Angry"], 1.7));
```

Answer (score 0):

This function explicitly checks for the "mid" case and also for out of range values (since it's based on indices):

```
function getEmotion(emotions, value) {

  // Out of range
  if ( value > emotions.length ) return emotions[emotions.length - 1];
  if ( value < 1 ) return emotions[0];

  // Determine if decimal is .5
  let mid = value % 1 === .5;
  // Round the value to the nearest integer
  let rounded = Math.round(value);

  return mid ? `${emotions[rounded - 2]} or ${emotions[rounded - 1]}` : emotions[rounded - 1];

}
```

Output:

```
let emotions = ['Happy', 'Happy', 'Sad', 'Glad', 'Angry'];

console.log(getEmotion(emotions, -23));    // Happy
console.log(getEmotion(emotions, 0));      // Happy
console.log(getEmotion(emotions, 1));      // Happy
console.log(getEmotion(emotions, 2.43));   // Happy
console.log(getEmotion(emotions, 2.5));    // Happy or Sad
console.log(getEmotion(emotions, 3.1));    // Sad
console.log(getEmotion(emotions, 155.65)); // Angry
```